# Page is refreshing and query won't take place - Ajax, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

```js
function add_comment(ele) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var username = "<?php echo $current_user; ?>";
  var user_id = "<?php echo $current_user_id; ?>";
  var post_id = $(ele).data('id');
  var comments = $(ele).parent(".comment-section").find(".comment").val();
  alert(comments);
  if (username == "") {
    alert("Please Log in to Star the Post");
    window.location = "http://tobbyandscooby.com/log.php";
    return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add_comment.php',
    data: {
      postid: post_id,
      uname: username,
      uid: user_id,
      comment: comments
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //alert("Successfully Comment is Added! ");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-section">
  <textarea id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="comment" value="" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>"></textarea>
  <button id="btn" class="btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" onclick="add_comment(this);">Comment</button>
  <div class="comment-show"></div>
</div>

<?php 
include("connect.php");
$username = $_POST['uname'];
$post_id = $_POST['postid'];
$user_id = $_POST['uid'];
$comments = $_POST['comment'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id,username,post_id,comment) VALUES ($user_id,'$username',$post_id,'$comment')";
$result = $db->query($sql);
?>
```

[image: Database Structure]

I am trying to make a comment system with Ajax. I have done similar thing like favourite, down vote, upvote with Ajax. But now with this above code, I couldn't enter the data into the DB and also on clicking comment button the page refreshes even though I have used *preventDefault();

I know I have made some mistake but couldn't debug it. Also please suggest me how to add the entered comment into *div .comment-show* using the success in ajax.

**NOTE: I could get the alert(comments); working when preventDefault(); function is removed!  I have added the XHR requests for other elements which are working fine! **

[image: XHR Request of Other Functions working Fine]

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I have used the same code for other functions like downvote, upvote, favourite which are working fine.
Also I have included the Jquery Library (Note: alert inside the add_comment(ele) function works and shows the entered comment!), I am testing the page on a live Godaddy server!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you please tell me how to check AJAX request in DEV tool? I have checked the network > XHR tab in inspector, and nothing show up. please note: only when I remove ele.preventDefault(); i get the alert(comment); otherwise page just refreshes.

Comment: Nothing shows in XHR but can see the request and response with other functions!

Comment: I doubt that the `ele.preventDefault();` works on an event of `onClick()` instead of an `onSubmit()`. Also `preventDefault` should be called on an event, not on an element.

Comment: @Jeff   Then can I use _$("#comment-btn").click(function() {});_ ?

Comment: Try event.preventDefault().

Comment: @KodosJohnson I tried but can't get into the ajax section!

Comment: In your code you are doing ele.prevenrDefault(). I'm telling you to change it to event.preventDefault(). It looks like ele is a Dom element. Ele doesn't have a prevent default function. You have to call prevent default on the global event object.

Comment: If you tried using `event`, then can you please update your code to show that? ele.preventDefault() doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yes, I have tried replacing ele.preventDefault(); but still the page refreshes!

Comment: Try adding `type="button"` to your button.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks for your time and suggestions. You got it nearly. In the console there was an error flashing about a half second on button click. I figured out it was a reference error and no event is defined. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `preventDefault()`.
You now pass `this` with that function call in `onClick`.

To solve it, make the button a submit-button by adding `<button type="submit" ..` 
and pass `event` with your function call: `...onClick="add_comment(event);"`

```
// complete line:
<button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" onclick="add_comment(event);">Comment</button>
```

But now you need to rewrite pieces of the function, because `ele` is now the event, not the element anymore:
Change every `$(ele)` to `$('#id')`

And obviously in the beginning of the function the variable name for the passed-in event needs to match:

```
function add_comment(e) { // whatever you wanna name it, e has to be the same 
   e.preventDefault();  // as this e
```

Another solution would be to keep the button just a normal button, remove the onClick there, and add `onSubmit="add_comment(event);"` to your `<form..>`

Comment: Thank you so Much @Jeff. That's got me the solution! 
I need to check the difference in *this and event* , and I found when I click the button there was a reference error is flashing for which you given the solution.
Thanks for your effort! :)

Comment: Don't know bro. I did neutralized it! ;)  @Jeff

Comment: If can please tell me how to append the comments on the *div.comment-show* ! 
How to use the **success:** ?

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks for the edit and the reversion of the downvote!

Comment: Sure, it didn't let me reverse my downvote if there weren't any edits. About my downvote: It wasn't clear to me what the OP's problem was and I don't know how changing the button type, passing the event in the function call, and removing the ele variable would help the OP. In fact I still don't know why using a regular button is a problem. But there is nothing wrong with your answer and it seems to have helped the OP so I reversed my downvote **and upvoted**.

Comment: the normal button just didn't trigger the submit event (at least on chrome), therefor wouldn't let the event be prevented (I did some testing before writing the answer)

Comment: @Jeff After a long try, I could correctly append the result back to my HTML using AJAX. ;)